# Does variables/functions/procedures/etc name affect performance in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, naming-conventions, sql

I'm almost a newbie coming from the "Java's World" to the "PL/SQL World", working with "legacy" stored procedures, and I have a question.
Best practices for Java naming includes tips such as "the names of variables, methods, classes, etc should be meaningful and auto-documented" (I read on the Clean Coder book).
By default, Oracle's identifiers are 30 characters length, but I've found abbreviated naming that not always are "easy translatable", and I don't know if that is done thinking on the app performance or it's "just a bad practice".

Supose I've found something like this:

```
PROCEDURE PROCCALCTAXES(vVarNamTax VARCHAR2(2)) IS 
   vVarNamCouCalTax VARCHAR2(20);
   nVarCouId NUMBER;
   vVarNamTax VARCHAR2(20);
   vVarValTax VARCHAR2(10);
   nVarCouTaxTimPaid NUMBER;
   vVarExa30Cha VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   --business logic
END PROCDOSTH;
```

There's something to take care of If I refactor that code like this?

```
PROCEDURE P_CALCULATE_TAXES(vVarNamTax VARCHAR2(2)) IS 
   vCountryName VARCHAR2(20);
   nCountryId NUMBER;
   vTaxName VARCHAR2(20);
   vTaxValue VARCHAR2(10);
   nCountOfTimesPaid NUMBER;
   vAnExampleWith30CharactersLong VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   --business logic
END P_CALCULATE_TAXES;
```

Is there a decrease on the performance of the app? What if all variables would be like the last one, with 30 characters? When does a name of a function/procedure/trigger/etc affect the performance? Is there a standard for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with performance, everything to do with maintainability and namespace management. Best practice would be to encapsulate all procedures within packages, e.g. `TAX_PKG.calculate` or `FINANCE.calculate_tax` or something that makes sense in your context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely make the names more readable, meaningful and auto-documenting. It would be hard to come across any language where a more descriptive name would be disadvantageous (maybe in some codegolf specific languages due to length constraints), at least in terms of performance. Sql and PL/Sql are no different. The name does not affect performance.

There is a 30 character limit though and if you are in an organization with multiple developers, you should definitely think about adopting a standard for parameter names, variable names, globals, any kind of prefixes/suffixes for views, triggers, procedures, packages etc.

You could visit http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/8245.plsql-standards.aspx to see some examples of standards that different people have adopted for them. There is no hard rule that says if something is correct or something is wrong. But there are certain standards that definitely help you improve the readability, maintainability of your code and possibly help write future code faster.

As for your example, I would totally encourage changing the name from `PROCCALCTAXES` to something more readable like `CALCULATE_TAXES` or if you adopted a standard to prefix procedures by `P_` or `PRC_`, that is up to you, but redundant in my opinion and takes up valuable real-estate in the 30 character space.

Another thing that I've found useful is to come up with a standard list of abbreviations applicable to our company. Like ORG for organization, ADDR for address, CUST for customer etc. Helps to fit words in the 30 char limit.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names have no impact on performance.

Regardless of the language, variable names should be clear and self-documenting.  Given that PL/SQL variable names are limited to 30 characters, however, making things clear and self-documenting may involve some sort of consistent abbreviation.  If I know, for example, that I'm going to have a number of different variables

```
order_id
order_line_id
order_line_amount
order_total_amount
order_sales_tax_rate
order_sales_tax_amount
order_sales_tax_taxing_entity_name
order_sales_tax_taxing_entity_fips_code
```

where some of the variables would exceed 30 characters, it often makes sense to abbreviate all of them consistently rather than only abbreviating those variables that would exceed 30 characters.  In this case, I may want to consistently abbreviate "order" as "ordr", "sales_tax" as "stax", and "taxing_entity" as "txety" in order to ensure that all my variables are less than 30 characters.  Forcing developers to know those abbreviations (and to stick to them consistently) is going to decrease the readability of your code but the hit is probably less than forcing developers to figure out whether you abbreviated "sales_tax" in one variable but not another.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it does not make any sense to use names like "**PROC**CALCTAXES" or "**vVar**NamTax" in order to show they are procedures or varchar variables. Almost each editor or IDE shows such information anyway by default. Use the characters to give more readable names.